# How to reduce AWS Lambda start up time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, discord

I am trying to use AWS Lambda to respond to Discord interactions. Currently my lambda takes around 1.1 seconds to start up and cannot respond within the required 3 seconds. I have tried to defer the response to Discord however that also takes more than 3 seconds 90% of the time. Is there anything I can do to reduce the start up time? The lambda is running python 3.9 and has 4 layers attached.

Comment: If you have that hard a limit on response times, your only chance is to not have instances cold start, which means you’ll need reserved capacity. Which’ll cost you.

Comment: Do you need all those layers?

Comment: I thought layers would help with Lambda start up times for some reason @jarmod ? Are you saying if it has more layers it will take longer to start up?

Comment: This study seems to find no significant difference in start up time for cold or hot Lambdas with or without layers: https://medium.com/consulner/performance-of-aws-lambda-with-and-without-layers-9bffbb5434f3 but it does seem to be a rather naive study, not really looking at the size of layers.

Comment: I'm not aware that how you package the code (a single ZIP vs smaller, single ZIP + single layer vs. smaller, single ZIP + multiple layers) makes any real difference in performance. I think your goal should be to minimize the size of your dependencies and, if it's feasible, use the lowest latency, highest performance runtime & language that you can, which is likely to be Rust or Go. Or use [provisioned concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/), of course.